# Print indel/mismatch in a blastp stream

Tags: blast, parsing, java

I am in need of a simple tool that accepts an XML file generated by a BlastP as input and gives me back a file containing information about mismatches/indels/etc. Fortunately such a tool already exists, but it works specifically with XML files generated by BlastN: http://lindenb.github.io/jvarkit/BlastNToSnp.html

I'm trying to adapt the code so that it also reads BlastP files, but after adapting the code it gives me both information about matches and mismatches in the output, and since my knowledge of Java is quite limited I can't identify the problem. Can someone with more expertise in java help me?

```
package com.github.lindenb.jvarkit.tools.blast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.List;

import gov.nih.nlm.ncbi.blast.Hit;
import gov.nih.nlm.ncbi.blast.Hsp;
import gov.nih.nlm.ncbi.blast.Iteration;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLResolver;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.events.XMLEvent;

import htsjdk.samtools.util.CloserUtil;

import com.github.lindenb.jvarkit.io.IOUtils;
import com.github.lindenb.jvarkit.util.bio.AcidNucleics;

import com.beust.jcommander.Parameter;
import com.github.lindenb.jvarkit.util.jcommander.Launcher;
import com.github.lindenb.jvarkit.util.jcommander.Program;
import com.github.lindenb.jvarkit.util.log.Logger;

@Program(name="blastp2snp",
    keywords={"blast","snp"},
    description="print indel/mismatch in a blastp stream",
    biostars={89151,455765},
    modificationDate="20200831",
    creationDate="20131126"
    )
public class BlastPToSnp extends Launcher
{
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.build(BlastPToSnp.class).make();


    @Parameter(names={"-o","--output"},description=OPT_OUPUT_FILE_OR_STDOUT)
    private File outputFile = null;


    @Parameter(names={"-n","--gapsize"},description="min gap")
    private int minGapSize = 3 ;

    private Unmarshaller unmarshaller;
    private Marshaller marshaller;
    /* force javac to compile */
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private gov.nih.nlm.ncbi.blast.ObjectFactory _ignore_for_javac=null;
    
    
    private Iteration peekIteration(final XMLEventReader r) throws XMLStreamException,JAXBException
        {
        while(r.hasNext())
            {
            final XMLEvent evt=r.peek();
            if(!(evt.isStartElement()))
                {
                r.next();
                continue;
                }
            final String name=evt.asStartElement().getName().getLocalPart();
            if(name.equals("BlastOutput_program"))
                {
                r.next();
                String prog=r.getElementText();
                if(!"blastp".equals(prog))
                    {
                    throw new XMLStreamException("Not a blastp input:"+prog);
                    }
                continue;
                }
            
            if(!name.equals("Iteration"))
                {
                r.next();
                continue;
                }
            
            return this.unmarshaller.unmarshal(r, Iteration.class).getValue();
            }
        return null;
        }
    
    
private void run(
        PrintWriter pw,
        XMLEventReader r
        )
        throws XMLStreamException,JAXBException
    {
     long numIterations=0L;
     long numPerfectMath=0L;
     long numNoHit=0L;
     
    
    pw.print("#query");
    pw.print('\t');
    pw.print("hit");
    pw.print('\t');
    pw.print(("hit-index"));
    pw.print('\t');
    pw.print("hsp-index");
    
    pw.print('\t');
    pw.print("query-POS");
    pw.print('\t');
    pw.print("hit-POS");
    pw.print('\t');
    pw.print("STRAND");
    
    pw.print('\t');
    pw.print("REF(hit)");
    pw.print('\t');
    pw.print("ALT(query)");
    pw.print('\t');
    pw.print("blast.align_length");
    pw.print('\t');
    pw.print("blast.hit.var");
    pw.print('\t');
    pw.print("blast.query.var");
    pw.print('\t');
    pw.print("blast.mid.var");
    
    pw.println();
    for(;;)
        {

        Iteration iter1=peekIteration(r);
        if(iter1==null) break;
        ++numIterations;
        if(iter1.getIterationHits().getHit().isEmpty())
            {
            LOG.info("No hit found for "+iter1.getIterationQueryDef());
            ++numNoHit;
            continue;
            }
        boolean found_mismatch=false;
        for(int hit_loop=0; hit_loop <  iter1.getIterationHits().getHit().size();++hit_loop)
            {
            final Hit hit=iter1.getIterationHits().getHit().get(hit_loop);
            for(int  hsp_loop =0;hsp_loop< hit.getHitHsps().getHsp().size();++hsp_loop)
                {
                final Hsp hsp = hit.getHitHsps().getHsp().get(hsp_loop);
                String hspQseq=hsp.getHspQseq();
                String hspMid=hsp.getHspMidline();
                String hspHSeq=hsp.getHspHseq();
                
                int hsp_query_from=Integer.parseInt(hsp.getHspQueryFrom());
                int hsp_query_to=Integer.parseInt(hsp.getHspQueryTo());
                int hsp_hit_from=Integer.parseInt(hsp.getHspHitFrom());
                int hsp_hit_to=Integer.parseInt(hsp.getHspHitTo());
                final int align_length=Integer.parseInt(hsp.getHspAlignLen());
                final int hit_shift=(hsp_hit_from>hsp_hit_to?-1:1);
                
                int i=0;
                int query_index = hsp_query_from;
                int hit_index = hsp_hit_from;
                
                while( i< align_length )
                    {
                    char ch= hspHSeq.charAt(i);
                    char cq= hspQseq.charAt(i);
                    char cm= hspMid.charAt(i);
                    if(cm=='|')
                        {
                        ++i;
                        query_index++;
                        hit_index+=hit_shift;
                        continue;
                        }
                    found_mismatch=true;
                    
                    int j=i+1;
                    for(;;)
                        {
                        int k=hspMid.indexOf(' ', j);
                        if(k==-1 || k-j> minGapSize) break;
                        j=k+1;
                        }
                    
                    
                    String ref=new String(hspHSeq.substring(i, j)).replaceAll("[\\- ]", "");
                    String alt=new String(hspQseq.substring(i, j)).replaceAll("[\\- ]", "");
                    
                    
                    
                    if(hit_shift<0)
                        {
                        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder(alt.length());
                        for(int x=alt.length()-1;x>=0;--x)
                            {
                            sb.append(AcidNucleics.complement(alt.charAt(x)));
                            }
                        alt=sb.toString();
                        
                        sb=new StringBuilder(ref.length());
                        for(int x=ref.length()-1;x>=0;--x)
                            {
                            sb.append(AcidNucleics.complement(ref.charAt(x)));
                            }
                        ref=sb.toString();
                        
                        
                        }
                        
                    pw.print(iter1.getIterationQueryDef());
                    pw.print('\t');
                    pw.print(hit.getHitDef());
                    pw.print('\t');
                    pw.print((1+hit_loop));
                    pw.print('\t');
                    pw.print((1+hsp_loop));
                    
                    pw.print('\t');
                    pw.print(query_index);
                    pw.print('\t');
                    pw.print(hit_index);
                    pw.print('\t');
                    pw.print(hit_shift==1?'+':'-');
                    
                    pw.print('\t');
                    pw.print(ref);
                    pw.print('\t');
                    pw.print(alt);
                    
                    
                    pw.print('\t');
                    pw.print(align_length);
                    pw.print('\t');
                    pw.print(hspHSeq.substring(i, j).replace(' ', '.'));
                    pw.print('\t');
                    pw.print(hspQseq.substring(i, j).replace(' ', '.'));
                    pw.print('\t');
                    pw.print(hspMid.substring(i, j).replace(' ', '.'));

                    
                    pw.println();
                    
                    //marshaller.marshal(new JAXBElement<Hsp>(new QName("Hsp"), Hsp.class, hsp), System.out);
                    //pw.println();
                    
                    while(i<j)
                        {
                        ch= hspHSeq.charAt(i);
                        cq= hspQseq.charAt(i);

                        if(ch!='-' && ch!=' ')
                            {
                            hit_index+=hit_shift;
                            }
                        if(cq!='-' && cq!=' ')
                            {
                            query_index++;
                            }
                        ++i;
                        }
                    }
                if(hit_index-hit_shift!=hsp_hit_to)
                    {
                    marshaller.marshal(new JAXBElement<Hsp>(new QName("Hsp"), Hsp.class, hsp),stderr());
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Error expected hit-index= "+hit_index+"-"+hit_shift+" == hsp-hit-to="+hsp_hit_to);
                    }
                if(query_index-1!=hsp_query_to)
                    {
                    marshaller.marshal(new JAXBElement<Hit>(new QName("Hit"), Hit.class, hit),stderr());
                    throw new IllegalStateException("query_index "+query_index+"(1 != hsp_query_to:"+hsp_query_to);
                    }
                if(pw.checkError()) break;
                }
            
            }//end loop Hit
        
        if(!found_mismatch)
            {
            numPerfectMath++;
            }
        
        }//end while read
    LOG.info("ITERATIONS : " +numIterations);
    LOG.info("ONLY_PERFECT_MATCH : " +numPerfectMath);
    LOG.info("NO_HIT : " +numNoHit);
    }
    
    @Override
    public int doWork(final List<String> args) {
        PrintWriter pw=null;
        XMLEventReader rx=null;
        try
            {
            
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("gov.nih.nlm.ncbi.blast");
            this.unmarshaller=jc.createUnmarshaller();
            this.marshaller=jc.createMarshaller();
            this.marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT,true);
            this.marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT,true);
            XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory=XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
            xmlInputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_NAMESPACE_AWARE, Boolean.FALSE);
            xmlInputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_COALESCING, Boolean.TRUE);
            xmlInputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_REPLACING_ENTITY_REFERENCES, Boolean.TRUE);
            xmlInputFactory.setProperty(XMLInputFactory.IS_SUPPORTING_EXTERNAL_ENTITIES, Boolean.FALSE);
            xmlInputFactory.setXMLResolver(new XMLResolver()
                {
                @Override
                public Object resolveEntity(String arg0, String arg1, String arg2,
                        String arg3) throws XMLStreamException
                    {
                    LOG.info("resolveEntity:" +arg0+"/"+arg1+"/"+arg2);
                    return null;
                    }
                });
            final String inputName= oneFileOrNull(args);
            if(inputName==null)
                {
                LOG.info("Reading from stdin");
                rx=xmlInputFactory.createXMLEventReader(stdin());
                }
            else
                {
                LOG.info("Reading from "+inputName);
                rx=xmlInputFactory.createXMLEventReader(IOUtils.openURIForBufferedReading(inputName));
                }
            pw = super.openFileOrStdoutAsPrintWriter(outputFile);
            run(pw,rx);
            pw.flush();
            return RETURN_OK;
            }
        catch(Exception err)
            {
            LOG.error(err);
            return -1;
            }
        finally
            {
            CloserUtil.close(rx);
            CloserUtil.close(pw);
            }
        }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new BlastPToSnp().instanceMainWithExit(args);

    }

}
```